# CSV read error: new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: python, csv

I created a python script which works with a test CSV dataset of 10 records. When I scaled this up to the actual datasets (a few thousand rows), I am getting the following error:

> _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

The code is as follows:

```
with open('./Origins.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    origincoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
```

The full error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Driving.py", line 14, in <module>
    origincoords = ['{Y},{X}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 103, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Perhaps there is a scale problem with the CSV reading method I am using?

Comment: You need to open your CSV files in *binary* mode: `open('./Origins.csv', 'rb')`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [PEP-0278](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/):

> In a Python with universal newline support open() the mode parameter
> can also be "U", meaning "open for input as a text file with universal
> newline interpretation". Mode "rU" is also allowed, for symmetry with
> "rb"

So try to change

```
with open('./Destinations.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

to

```
with open('./Destinations.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
```

If the error persists, change to

```
with open('./Destinations.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
```

---

Edited accorded to Martijn Pieters's comment.

Comment: The OP should first try `rb` instead of `r`; if the message persists `'rU'` could be used.

Comment: Many thanks Martijn and @fredtantini. rb did not work but rU did. I dont understand the difference as yet, so I will read up on it. Many thanks

Comment: `rU` worked but the others didn't. Why was that? I don't understand why that one worked but the others would not.