# Parsing tab delimited string results in new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have a tab-delimited text file that is saved in a database field. When I try to parse the text/string content (from the database field), I keep getting the error `new-line character seen in unquoted field`.

A lot of SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102302/csv-read-error-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field)) deal with reading a file directly and specify `with open(path, 'rb') as f` or `with open(path, 'rU')`. However, I can't use `with open(...)` since I am reading the text/string value from a database record/field.

A simple example demonstrates my problem below.

```
import csv

s = """X    Y   A   B   C   D
E
F"""

list(csv.reader([s], delimiter='\t'))[0] # throws error
```

Conceptually, the line is `X\tY\tA\t\B\t\C\tD\rE\rF\r\n`.

What I would expect is `['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D\rE\rF']`.

If the field is quoted, then everything works. But I have no control upstream over how these text are generated (impossible to control and re-export). Example below.

```
s = """X    Y   A   B   C   "D
E
F"
"""
list(csv.reader([s], delimiter='\t', quotechar='"'))[0]
```

Any ideas on how I can get this parsing to work?

Comment: Do all the rows have the same number of columns?  If so you could split the text by newline, then each row by tab; rows with embedded newlines will be short, and so  recognisable.  Then write the lines into a csv so that they get quoted properly, if you need csv.